# Android : Toggle visibility of multiple controls via code

Tags: android, android-layout

I am looking for best practice to toggle visibility of multiple controls at same time.  For eg:

There are 5 Buttons in layout and i want to toggle visibility of 4 buttons to "Gone".  What will be the best way to do this?

Is finding controls i.e. view.FindViewById the only way to achieve this?  The option of putting them into another container like LinearLayout is also not feasible because i don't want to increase my layout complexity.

Comment: Add your buttons into a Array or something to manager them, loop or brower this data struct to GONE your child control

Comment: Like the idea of looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on android reminds me of Winform days, you have to iterate through all the controls, find them and take the action.  Here is code snippet i wrote to get desired result.

```
var myLayout = searchView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.myLayout);
        for (int count = 0; count < myLayout.ChildCount; count++) 
        {
            // Hide all controls in layout except details Imageview 
            if (myLayout.GetChildAt (count).Id != Resource.Id.IdOfControlThatIDontWantToHide)
                gestureControlLayout.GetChildAt (count).Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

        }
```

This code is written in Xamarin.Android.